# What is the use of "or" operator with integers

Tags: javascript, or-operator

I am not getting what `or` operator does with inters. I have following code

```
-1||4  // output -1
4||-1  //output  4
```

Does it converts integers in bytes and performs or operation.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: Only the number `0` is *falsey*... does that help?

Answer (score 3):

It first checks wheter the number is `truthy` or `falsey` and returns the first `truthy` one. All numbers are truthy except for `0`.

```
0  || 4;  //  4
2  || 3;  //  2 (picks the first one, because both true)
-3 || 0;  // -3
0  || -2; // -2
```

> Does it converts integers in bytes and performs or operation?

No. The `||` operator is `logical and`, not `bitwise and`.

Comment: It returns the first truthy value, or the last one unconditionally if all the preceding ones are falsey. So `0 || 0` returns `0` because the first value is falsey and the last value is zero.